# How to append li items to fisrt ul of given id

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to access the first `<ul>` inside 2 (more) `div`s of given `div` `<div class="form-group" id="contract">` i.e. `$('#contract')`

**Code**:

```
<div class="form-group" id="contract">
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select search-fields open">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle bs-placeholder btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" data-id="ct" title="Contract Types" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="filter-option pull-left">Contract Types</span>&nbsp;
                <span class="bs-caret">
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </span>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox" style="max-height: 590px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 158px;">
            <div class="bs-searchbox">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search value" role="textbox" aria-label="Search">
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true" style="max-height: 543px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 111px;">
                <li data-original-index="0" class="selected active">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="true">
                        <span class="text">Contract Types</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="1">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Rent</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="2">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Buy</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="3">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Commercial Rent</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li data-original-index="4">
                    <a tabindex="0" class="" data-tokens="null" role="option" aria-disabled="false" aria-selected="false">
                        <span class="text">Commercial Buy</span>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>

                <-- *** I want to append new li items here using $('#contract') of parent's parent's parent (3rd parent's) div *** -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <select class="selectpicker search-fields" id="ct" name="ct" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-placeholder="Search value" tabindex="-98">
            <option value="">Contract Types</option>
            <option value="1">Rent</option>
            <option value="2">Buy</option>
            <option value="3">Commercial Rent</option>
            <option value="4">Commercial Buy</option> 
            <-- *** here, I can append a new option like *** -->
            <script>
                $('#ct').append('<option value="5">New option</option>');
            </script>                                                                                                   
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I append an `<li>` item to (first & only) `<ul>` using first div's id with jQuery.
*Target div is not the parent but parent's parent's parent.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to find the element in all of its children and then use method `.append()` to append some html to the jquery object returned in previous step.

```
$("#contract").find(".dropdown-menu").append('<li>li Content</li>')
```

Comment: You are life saver man! Thank you so much...
Just one favor... Can I clear/empty the ul like this as well???

Comment: @talesid `$("#contract").find(".dropdown-menu").empty()` should do the thing. Do mark the answer correct if it solves the doubt! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the new item as the first one in the list, use the prepend method. Otherwise, use append.

`$('#contract').find('ul').prepend('<li>added node</li>')`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafaelrozon/1uny3d1s/)

If possible, you can add a css class or id to the ul element and use that as the selector in jquery. If it's not possible, you can make your selector more precise to avoid selecting the wrong node, for example `$('#contract .dropdown-menu > ul').prepend('<li>added node</li>')`